# Android keeps asking for adb permission

Tags: android, adb

I have this weird issue, that whenever I connect my phone to my computer the computer will always ask for the phone's adb permission, even though I mark the "Always allow from this computer" option everytime it asks.

I tried the following things, but none of them worked:

- Revoke USB debugging authorizations in dev options.
- Invalidate chaches in Android Studio (though I doubt it's a problem with the IDE).
- Reinstall the usb driver.
- Try different cables.

It doesn't affect the development but it's really annoying that I have to authroize everytime I connect my phone.

It happens with both my phone and my tablet. It only happens on my desktop, it doesn't happen on my laptop. It also happens when Android Studio isn't even running. I tried 2 different cables and it happened with both of them.

So I highly suspect it's a problem with the driver or windows. But I have no idea where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with updating `platform-tools` package to version `23.0.0rc2`

Comment: it is on 23 rc2, but I'm gonna try downgrading down to 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to down grade Platform-tools from `23.0.0 rc2` to `22.0.0`

Comment: my point was that the `platform-tools` version has to match (to be compatible with) the build on the device. I work with fairly recent builds myself - so my suggestion was to "upgrade"