# Android Phone keeps asking to allow Debug USB - Android Studio on Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, adb

I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.04/64bit to learn and develop with Android Studio, and one annoying thing that keeps bugging me is that every time I connect the phone via cable to run the app, it ask me to allow for USB debug from that particular device (my laptop). I even tried using adb over wifi, but as soon as i lock the screen the device disconnects and I have to send the request to connect the device and re-authorize again.

I did a bit of search and found this post with the same problem:
[Android keeps asking for adb permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922838/android-keeps-asking-for-adb-permission)

So I first tried following the OP's steps, with no luck. Then I tried the solution in the answer: *"I had to downgrade Platform-tools from 23.0.0 rc2 to 22.0.0"*

Problem is, I can't downgrade or upgrade the Platform-tools package, because I have only one version available on my Sdk Manager, and that's version 22.

Any help towards solving this problem is appreciated!